# Javascript only parsing the last element of array

Tags: javascript

Having an issue where str.replace only works in the last element of my array
here is the array:

`["omao","carlton","judging"]`

and here is my javascript function

```js
function emoji(data){
 
 //console.log(data);

 
 $(".message-content").each(function(){
  var elem = $(this);
  var str = elem.html();
  //var res = str.replace(":hey", '<img draggable="false" class="emoji jumboable" alt="emoji" src="https://discordchat.com/api/omao.png">');
  for(var i = 0;i < data.length; i++){
   var res = str.replace(":"+data[i], '<img draggable="false" title="Added using the WLA Poor Mans Nitro" class="emoji jumboable" alt="emoji" src="https://discordchat.com/api/'+data[i]+'.png" />');
   elem.html(res);
  }
  
  
 });
 
}
```

When you run it, only `:judging` gets replaced by the image, `:omao` and `:carlton` is ignored. Ive tried every "solution" I could find but all with the same issue.

Comment: Updated the snippet, there was a bug in pasting.

Comment: Don't forget to [accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), seeing you have a zero acceptance rate, though you already asked more than 15+ answers

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that you are repeating the replace on the original string, and not on the already changed string, which is why only the last iteration is the one that gets set

You can change it like so

```
var str = elem.html();
for(var i = 0;i < data.length; i++){
    str = str.replace(":"+data[i], '<img draggable="false" title="Added using the WLA Poor Mans Nitro" class="emoji jumboable" alt="emoji" src="https://discordchat.com/api/'+data[i]+'.png" />');
}
// and set it only once
elem.html(res);
```

Comment: Wowo this was humiliating. Thanks so much, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
elem.html(res);
```

to

```
elem.append(res);
```

If running this multiple times (like .click()) you will want to put `elem.empty()` right before your `.each()`.

Comment: from what I see, he problably has a html like `:amao :carlton :judging` (seeing he preloads the elements html content) And just wants to replace does strings inside the single element